# Centralize div and scale to fit screen

Tags: css, html, mobile, centralized

For my website I have been trying to centralize the entire content for display on mobile devices:

http://m.bachatdeals.com

As soon as I open the website on a mobile device, it has lots of space below the content and I have to pinch zoon to be able to read, how do I remove the extra space below so that my content perfectly fits in the center of the mobile device?

I have tried quiet a few CSS workarounds, but something or the other breaks my layout , please help !

Note : right now its not automatically redirecting to mobile devices so you would have to manually type in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to the head of your mobile pages:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`